# I know react-native's TextInput has a onsubmit callback function, but how do i actually make that submit button?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to know how to render this button and if so is it autobound to the text in the input field ?

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 46):

Basically `onSumbitEditing` will trigger and event provided when go button is clicked from android soft keyboard as in below example :

```
 <TextInput
  style={[styles.zipCode, styles.mainText]}
  returnKeyType='My Custom button'
  onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.updateText( event.nativeEvent.text
   )}/>
```

in above code snippet : 
I have action name is 'My Custom button' which will appera in soft keyboard in android and when you press that the updateText event is tiggered , thats what is the meaning on onSubmitEditing

Note : if physical keyboard is enable in android emulator so onSubmitEditing will not tigger any event since you would not be also to press virtual key which is given name as 'My Custom Button'

Answer (score 6):

You can have something like this :

```
onSubmitEdit = () => {
  // whatever you want to do on submit
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign="center"
        onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitEdit} />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onSubmitEdit}>
        <Text>Press this button to submit editing</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is `onSubmitEditing` that you're passing to `<TextInput />` and what is the callback you're passing to it? I'm trying to find out if `<TouchableHighlight onPress={whatever}>` is the relevant part that's analogous to a form `onSubmit`, or whether `onSubmitEditing` is necessary too.

Comment: You have all the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)
Basically, `onSubmitEditing`is called when your submit button is pressed.
Check the example [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.ios.js#L75-L77) to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

The onSubmit callback is called when you hit the done/return/join on the keyboard that pops out