# React Native - Difference between onChangeText and onSubmitEditing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

From the Facebook React Native Text Input documentation, I was able to discern that this is what happens when `onSubmitEditing` is used:

> Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed.

However, there wasn't anything for `onChangeText`. I'm assuming if the text has changed, then it will trigger.

Why would I want to use one other than the other? For example if I'm making something that takes in text for the `TextInput` field, wouldn't I just want to use `onChangeText`? In some examples I've seen them use `onSubmitEditing` and I'm confused on why you would use one over the other. This question is different than wondering how to make the submit button - I'm asking why I would use `onChangeText` vs. `onSubmitEditing`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I know react-native's TextInput has a onsubmit callback function, but how do i actually make that submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991837/i-know-react-natives-textinput-has-a-onsubmit-callback-function-but-how-do-i-a)

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I'm not sure how my question is a duplicate of the suggested one when I'm asking for the difference between `onChangeText` vs. `onSubmitEditing`, whereas that thread asks how to create a submit button for `onSubmitEditing`.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. onChangeText gets called everytime the text in the TextInput changes but this also means every single time. So for example to implement something like suggestive search your data filters everytime your text changes. A good solution is to debounce the text change event so that it does the filtering after say a 500ms timeout.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`onSubmitEditing` is triggered when you click the text input submit button (keyboard button).

`onChangeText` is triggered when you type any symbol in the text input.

For example, you might need some validation on every key press, in that case you will use `onChangeText`, if you need the validation to trigger when you finish typing, you need `onSubmitEditing`

In your example, you will achieve what you need in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

`onSubmitEditing` is a callback when you tap the button in the screenshot below.

[image: onSubmitEditing]

`onChangeText` is a callback when you type anything into a `TextInput`.

Answer (score 1):

**1: [`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting)**

[`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting) : When you want to submit the editing of text field and want to call some action like dimissing the mobile keyboard or calling submit action or API to pass current screen data,one can use it.

In short,when you are done with adding the text to field and want to proceed with some action to next Screen,one can use it.

It called only when one press the keyboard button.
e.g. When we press GO,RETURN,Search button on keyboard.

**2: [`onChangeText`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext)**

[`onChangeText`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext) : Its typical use to update the state of Component with TextInput value like Reactjs `onChange` event.

Its called on every change of character.